# Java connection to Windows SQL Server 2005

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, connection

This is an issue that has really been killing me, so I figured I would take it to you fine gentlemen/women to see if we can get a solution.

I am trying to connect to a SQL server 2005 (MSSQLSERVER, not SERVEREXPRESS or anything like that) I have set up on a machine running Windows Server from my labtop. My labtop is using a java connection string with JDBC 4.0 (via Netbeans IDE) JDK 1.7. It uses windows authentication. The connection code is the following:

```
    String url;
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://[Server IP Address]\\[Instance Name]:1433;integratedSecurity=true";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Instance name = UB-TCMG
Note: After [Server IP Address] there are two backslashes. If there is only one backslash, it is counted as an escape character. Two seems to only count as one.

Unfortunately, I don't have the error with me at this moment. Basically, it said "Connection refused: connection"

On the server side, I have done the following based upon online research. Enabled the TCP/IP port in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Erased all Dynamic TCP Ports. TCP Ports are 1433. VIA is enabled.

As well, surface area connection has been used to activate the SQL browser.

Using telnet from the laptop does not allow any connection.
Using telnet on the server works when:
telnet [Server Instance Name] 1433

Both firewalls have been shut off.

logs say "Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433]"

There's more I tried to solve this issue, but I'm literally falling asleep and can't remember. Anything you can suggest to help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The problem was two-fold. One, my laptop was accessing the internet via a static IP address. When I changed it to dynamic, I was able to connect to the server via land-line using a derivative of the above connection string.

The second problem has to do with the network I am using. For some reason, it blocks wireless access to the server. This is something I will resolve with the IT of the network. Still, I can access it through land-line since the IT has not blocked the relevant ports/addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how you will do connection in Java

```
import java.sql.*;

public class testConnection
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DB db = new DB();
        db.dbConnect(
     "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/tempdb","sa","");
    }
}

class DB
{
    public DB() {}

    public voidn dbConnect(String db_connect_string, 
  String db_userid, String db_password)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
            System.out.println("connected");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

This article might help please visit this link:  http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-connect-microsoft-sql-server-using-jdbc.html

Comment: @Moiz Thank you for the quick response. I get a Connection Timed Out error with this code. Since I have been unable to telnet to the server, I kind of suspect the source of my problem is the server side, not the java side. 

EDIT:

Sorry, it seems my server was turned off. After turning it on and running the code, I get the following error:
     "java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect"

Never gotten the network IO exception before...

Comment: @MatthewBreland : have you checked your connection string ?

Comment: @Moiz in what way? My connection string is the same as what you posted, except testdb has been replaced with an actual database on the server.
I have checked, and there is an sa user registered on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might work for You..

```
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=dbname;user=uname;password=pass";
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,but unfortunately the code just generates a "Connection refused: connect" error.